# Ошибка Floating point exception (core dumped)

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Есть код для деления чисел на наибольший общий множитель:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return (a == 0) ? b: gcd(b % a, a);
}
 
int main() {
    int n, m = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        arr[i] = a;
        m = gcd(m, a);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << arr[i]/m << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

На 6 тест выдает ошибку:

```
Failed test #6 of 10. Runtime error

Error:
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

Не совсем понимаю, в чем проблема

Задача:
Для умного города выбирают компанию, которая будет разрабатывать беспилотные автобусы. Для этого все компании-участники представили свои прототипы, а жюри оценивало проделанную работу каким-либо целым неотрицательным количеством баллов. Члены жюри сложили все свои оценки, чтобы получить итоговую оценку прототипа. Однако из-за большого количества членов жюри числа получились плохо воспринимаемыми для человека.

Ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать оценки более удобными для восприятия человеком. Это подразумевает под собой выполнение следующих пунктов:

Все оценки должны оставаться целыми числами.
Соотношения между оценками разных прототипов не должны измениться.
Числа должны быть минимально возможными с учётом выполнения всех остальных пунктов.
Если оценки упростить не получается, то следует оставить их в первоначальном виде.
Ввод:

В первой строке идёт целое число N - количество оцененных прототипов. (1 <= N <= 500)

В следующей строке находятся N оценок компонентов до приведения к удобному виду. Каждая оценка не превышает 10 000 000 000 баллов и больше или равна 0.

Вывод:

Строка с N целыми числами - оценками компонентов после приведения к удобному виду в соответствующем порядке.

Comment: А тесты где проходите? URL? чтобы посмотреть, какие ограничения на входные данные.

Comment: Неправильно обрабатывается такой пример: `1 0`. Есть ситуации когда `gcd` может вернуть ноль. В дальнейшем вы на этот ноль поделите.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну правильно, gcd получается 0, и деление на 0...

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке у меня такое же. Что ясности не добавляет. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Нужно точное условие задачи. Что мы гадаем? Там оговорено все. Без точного ТЗ результат один - ХЗ. Почему-то люди к врачам не ходят с "у меня где-то болит, но что и где - не ваше дело", а вот на ruSO - постоянно :( Еще раздражают люди, задающие вопрос и исчезающие на сутки - похоже, ответ их совершенно не интересует...

Comment: добавил условие